# Assigning worksheet range to an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to assign ranges in worksheets to array variables, and it is not working out so far. Not an expert on the subject in VB, any help is appreciated. The ranges I have typed in are definite, however the array declaration for row and column size is just a guess thus far. Thanks!

```
Dim runningavg(1 To 10000, 1 To 76), chartdata(1 To 598, 1 To 121) As Long

runningavg = Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Range("A4:BX10004")
chartdata = Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("B6:DR604")
```

Comment: change your Dim line to `Dim runningavg() As variant, chartdata() As Variant`

Comment: The first one should have worked...

Comment: I tried this, and the error is still saying that I "Can't assign to array". @Scott Craner

Comment: Oh and put `.Value` at the end of both `Range(...)`

Comment: Great catch. However I am still getting the same error and I am not sure why

Comment: Disregard that! it is now working haha. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work - a `Variant` can be assigned to just about *anything*:

```
Dim runningavg as variant, chartdata as variant

runningavg = Worksheets("Running Avg Log").Range("A4:BX10004").value
chartdata = Worksheets("Chart Data").Range("B6:DR604").value
```

You can't read a whole range into an array when the array is sized already and not a variant. To do it with a fixed array, you would need to write to the array cell by cell.

Comment: Make your statements more bold; `This will work` and remove the `I don't think`  When you are right you are right.

Answer (score -1):

I still got the same issue. Everything works fine since source data is in the same sheet. If you try to populate an array from a Range in different sheet, you got error 13.
No matter if you set the variable as Variant or add Worksheet("xxx") as source.
There's no solution for it.