How to search for the last occurrence of a value in a 2-D VBA array and then offset that index to find a different value?
A software of ours produces an Excel file with 28,000 rows and 64 columns. The Excel file has no data formatting; it is a mess of empty cells, titles, headers, tables within tables, etc. What is important for my purposes is finding the first occurrence of a value after the last occurrence of a different value, to import the right numbers into another Excel file. For example:
RANDOM DATA 123456           RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA 123456           RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA 123456           RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA      NEED THIS VALUE
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA      NEED THIS VALUE
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA
RANDOM DATA RANDOM DATA  RANDOM DATA

In the macro I made, using the Range.Find() method, I was able to find the cell position of the last 123456 and then Range.Offset() the number of rows and columns to find NEED THIS VALUE.
This works. However, I need to run the Range.Find() method more than 200 times over 28,000 rows, which makes the macro SLOW.
I wanted to instead save the worksheet into a 2-D array and find the values in the array instead of searching the worksheet. However, I am stumped on how to search for the last occurrence of a value in an array and then offset that index position to find a different value at a different index. What kind of loop would I need?
Edit. Adding in my old code because it was requested.
Function GetMiles(TruckList() As String, FilePath As String)
    Dim OOWorkbook As Workbook 'This main workbook
    Dim DSWorkbook As Workbook 'Driver settlement workbook
    Dim TruckNumber As String 'To Save truck number
    Dim truck As Variant 'To loop through array
    Dim YOS As String 'Value of revenue
    Dim IntA As Integer 'For counting
    Dim TruckRange As Range 'The range to search for the truck number
    Dim TruckWhere As Range 'To store the cell number of the truck and access range properties
    Dim YOSWhere As Range 'To store the cell of Years of Service and access range properties
    Dim LastTruckCell As String 'Cell of the last occurrence of the truck
    Dim YOSCell As String 'Cell of the first occurence of the Year of Service
    Dim YOSCellRange As Range 'The range to search for the value of YOS based on the location of Years of Service
    Dim YOSRange As Range 'The range to search for Years of Service
    Dim UTruckList As Integer 'Check array size
    Dim GrossEarningsRange As Range 'The range to search for Gross Earnings
    Dim GrossWhere As Range 'To store cell of Gross Earnings and access range properties
    Dim GrossCell As String 'To store cell position of Gross Earnings
    Dim GrossOrYOS As String 'To check if the above row is Years of Service or something else
    Dim LCV As String 'To check if the truck is LCV or not
    
    'Set the OO workbook
    Set OOWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Open Driver Settlement workbook
    Set DSWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    
    'TruckArray = TruckList()
    UTruckList = UBound(TruckList)
    
    IntA = 0
    
    'Loop through tuck array
    For Each truck In TruckList
        If IntA > UTruckList Then 'Make sure IntA is within array index to handle subscript out of range error
            Exit For
        Else
            TruckNumber = TruckList(IntA) 'Access array value
            If TruckNumber = "" Then
                'Do nothing
            Else
                Set TruckRange = DSWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange 'Set the range to look for the truck number
                Set TruckWhere = TruckRange.Find(What:=TruckNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious) 'Find the cell of the last occurrence of that truck number
                If (TruckWhere Is Nothing) Then 'Check if no truck was found
                    IntA = IntA + 1
                Else
                    LastTruckCell = TruckWhere.Address(0, 0) 'Get cell number of last occurence of truck number
                    Set GrossEarningsRange = DSWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
                    Set GrossWhere = GrossEarningsRange.Find(What:="Total Gross Earnings on Trips", After:=Range(LastTruckCell), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                    GrossCell = GrossWhere.Address(0, 0) 'Get cell position of Gross Earnings on Trips
                    Set YOSCellRange = DSWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range(GrossCell) 'Set the range to search for the YOS value based on the cell number of Years of Service
                    GrossOrYOS = YOSCellRange.Offset(-1, 0)
                    If GrossOrYOS = "YEARS OF SERVICE" Then
                        YOS = YOSCellRange.Offset(-1, 17) 'Get the value of the YOS
                        LCV = OOWorkbook.Worksheets(TruckNumber).Range("D4").Value
                        If LCV = "LCV" Then
                            OOWorkbook.Worksheets(TruckNumber).Range("F12").Value = YOS 'to assign YOS to LCV cell
                        Else
                            OOWorkbook.Worksheets(TruckNumber).Range("E12").Value = YOS 'Update truck sheet with YOS value
                        End If
                    Else
                        'Do nothing/skip
                    End If
                    IntA = IntA + 1
                    Call GetCityWork(FilePath, GrossCell, LastTruckCell, TruckNumber)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next truck
End Function


If you need help improving your code, then posting your code is the best way to get suggestions.  Questions without code tend to get closed here.

I don't have code though? I am asking how to code something like this. My old code isn't helpful or relevant because I want to attempt a different approach.

Your existing code tells us exactly what needs to be done though?  Eg are the values being searched in specific columns?   If you want to use an array then you can get the data into a 2D array using UsedRange.Value and loop backwards over it using (eg) a nested loop with Step -1.

Alright, well, I've added in my old code.

How slow is "slow"?  What is your current runtime like and what are you aiming for?

This question about assigning a worksheet Range to an array might help  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062626/assigning-worksheet-range-to-an-array

Here's one approach to how you can start thinking about the process:
Sub Tester()
    Dim arr(1 To 100) As String, i
    For i = 1 To 100 'make some dummy truck data
        arr(i) = "Truck" & Format(i, "000")
    Next i
    GetMiles arr, "" 'not using the path here...
End Sub



Function GetMiles(TruckList() As String, FilePath As String)
    Dim wbOO As Workbook, wsDS As Workbook, rng As Range, data, t
    Dim dictTrucks As Object, dictLast As Object, r As Long, c As Long, v, k
    
    t = Timer
    
    Set wbOO = ThisWorkbook 'Set the OO workbook
    
    'Set wbds = Workbooks.Open(FilePath) 'Open Driver Settlement workbook
    'Set rng = wbds.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BL$28000") '### for testing
    
    data = rng.Value 'get as 2D array

    Set dictTrucks = ArrayToDict(TruckList) 'use dictionary for quick lookup
    Set dictLast = GetDict()                'an empty dictionary

    'Loop array in reverse and find last instance of all trucks in TruckList
    For r = UBound(data, 1) To 1 Step -1
        For c = UBound(data, 2) To 1 Step -1
            v = CStr(data(r, c))
            If dictTrucks.Exists(v) Then  'in TruckList?
                dictTrucks.Remove v       'remove after first found
                dictLast(v) = Array(r, c) 'store where found
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t 'approx 2-3 sec for 100 trucks
    'these are the locations of the last instances of elements in TruckList
    For Each k In dictLast
        Debug.Print k, "is at", Join(dictLast(k), ",")
    Next k

End Function

'convert a string array to a dictionary for lookup
Function ArrayToDict(arr() As String) As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Set ArrayToDict = GetDict()
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        ArrayToDict.Add arr(i), False
    Next i
End Function

'return a case-insensitive dictionary object
Function GetDict() As Object
    Set GetDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    GetDict.CompareMode = 1
End Function


Thank you. What variable type is "data"? And what does this line mean: For r = UBound(data, 1) To 1 Step -1. I've seen this To 1 Step -1. What does this mean?

data is a Variant which holds a 2-dimensional array once it has been assigned to rng.Value.  The nested loops using Step -1 loop in reverse order from the "end" of the array to the beginning, by row and by column.

Was this helpful in speeding up your process?
